# enable button to be clicked only when all the form is filled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How could i enable button to be clicked only when all the fields are added? I can do this if i have to check for one field but here i have multiple fields with also select field. That is why I do not have idea on doing this. Here is the form i have done

```
class Registration extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    valueOfCategory: 1,
    valueOfPlatform: '',
  };

  handleCategoryChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({valueOfCategory: value});
  handlePlatformChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({valueOfPlatform: value});
  addPlatform = (event, index, value) => this.setState({ platform: value });
  addCategory = (event, index, value) => this.setState({ category: value });
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="registration">
        <Card>
          <TextField
            type="text"
            hintText="Bot name"
          /><br />
          <TextField
            type="text"
            hintText="Location"
          /><br />
          <SelectField
            value={this.state.valueOfCategory}
            onChange={this.handleCategoryChange}
            hintText="Category"
          >
            <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Food" />
            <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Travel" />
            <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Communication" />
          </SelectField>
          <FloatingActionButton onTouchTap={this.addCategory}><ContentAdd /></FloatingActionButton>
          <br/>
          <SelectField
            value={this.state.valueOfPlatform}
            onChange={this.handlePlatformChange}
            hintText="Platform"
          >
            <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Facebook" />
            <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="KIK" />
            <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Slack" />
          </SelectField>
          <FloatingActionButton onTouchTap={this.addPlatform}><ContentAdd /></FloatingActionButton>
          <br/>
          {this.state.valueOfPlatform === 1 && <FacebookPlatform />}
          <RaisedButton label="Done" />
        </Card>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`{(this.state.valueOfCategory || this.state.valueOfPlatform || this.state. platform || this.state.category ) && <RaisedButton label="Done" />}` 
Do something like this..

Answer (score 0):

You can do all logical calculation inside  `render()`, but before `return`. And there you just add multiple logical conditions:

```
var showButton = (this.state.value1 != "" || this.state.value2 === 1);
```

and then again use suitable logical operator:

```
{showButton ? <FacebookPlatform> : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this as well

```
const {valueOfCategory, valueOfPlatform, botName, location} = this.state;
const isEnabled = valueOfCategory.length > 0 && valueOfPlatform.length > 0 && botName.length > 0 && location.length > 0;
```

And in button `<RaisedButton label="Done" disabled={isEnabled} />`

I believe doing something like this works for you.